# Divide a number into equal range and return as rows using select for oracle database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, oracle11g

I am just asking, not sure if its feasible in an Oracle database select syntax, but below is a high level requirement.

Inputs

> - Suppose I have a number: 6534
> - Our dividing factor is "2000" for equal ranges

Output

```
RowNum  StartRange    EndRange  
1       1             2000  
2       2001          4000  
3       4001          6000  
4       6001          6534
```

Comment: We would need at least a high level example of what you tried.

Comment: Please state your database version, as returned when you run `select * from v$version`. You are showing `11g` already, which means version 11, and the Oracle marketing tag of "g" - but in this case, there is a big difference between 11.1 and 11.2. (The full version number, which you should ALWAYS provide, is in five parts, like 11.2.0.4.0.) Oracle 11.2 introduced recursive queries, which can be used as an alternative to `CONNECT BY` queries; not available in 11.1 though!

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu : I could not wrap my head trying to do this by select statement. Looking at below answers i am blown with my SQL knowledge! Complete enlightenment, everyday something new to learn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a Hierarchical Query to Create the Intervals**

I just used a hierarchical query to create the intervals.  My query does not check for division by zero.

It just checks that the level of the hierarchy is less than or equal to ceiling of the quotient (ceiling function returns the minimum integer greater than or equal to n).

```
    SCOTT@db>SELECT
  2      level intrvl,
  3      ( level - 1 ) * (:l_denominator ) + 1 low_bnd,
  4      least(:l_numerator,level *:l_denominator) up_bnd
  5  FROM
  6      dual
  7  CONNECT BY
  8      level <= ceil(:l_numerator /:l_denominator)
  9  /
  INTRVL   LOW_BND   UP_BND 
       1         1     2000 
       2      2001     4000 
       3      4001     6000 
       4      6001     6534
```

My initial answer had two query blocks to address the final interval where the modulus was greater than zero. This has been removed.

Also, mathguy made the observation that I really did not need my common table expression (serves no additional value). The common table expression has been removed.

Comment: You don't need a `WITH` clause to create a subquery, only to then - in the outer query - simply select everything from the subquery. Edit again to make the `select` from the `WITH` clause into the **entire** solution.

Comment: Solid input, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using (abusing?) hierarchical queries.

```
select min(data_column) StartRange,max(data_column) EndRange
from
(
  SELECT rownum data_column, trunc((rownum - 1)/ 2000, 0) round_col
  from DUAL
  connect by level <= 6534
)
group by round_col
order by round_col asc;
```

Helpful documentation:

1. Oracle [trunc(number)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm) function.  Keep in mind trunc(date) does something different.
2. Oracle [Hierarchical Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

Comment: Solid input, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do this with a recursive query (which requires Oracle version 11.2 or higher).

You need a way to provide the inputs to the query, too. In the illustration below I use the mechanism offered by SQL*Plus: I define two bind variables and I assign values to them. Then I reference these bind variables in the query. Depending on what you use (SQL Developer? A graphical user interface? Perhaps you may call the query from PL/SQL, or from Java, etc.?) - you will use the appropriate mechanism to provide the values to the query. (Or, alternatively, you may hard-code them directly in the query; not recommended!)

```
SQL> variable input_number    number     -- SQL*Plus command, no need for ; after it!
SQL> variable dividing_factor number
SQL> begin                               -- PL/SQL anonymous procedure to assign values
  2    :input_number    := 6534;
  3    :dividing_factor := 2000;
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SQL> with
  2    r ( r_num, start_range, end_range ) as (
  3      select  1, 1, least(:dividing_factor, :input_number)
  4        from  dual
  5      union all
  6      select  r.r_num + 1, r.start_range + :dividing_factor,
  7              least(r.end_range + :dividing_factor, :input_number)
  8        from  r
  9        where r.end_range < :input_number
 10    )
 11  select   r_num, start_range, end_range
 12  from     r
 13  order by r_num    --    If needed.
 14  ;

     R_NUM START_RANGE  END_RANGE
---------- ----------- ----------
         1           1       2000
         2        2001       4000
         3        4001       6000
         4        6001       6534
```